# How do i make menu with javascript that dynamically changes the content on the website

Tags: javascript, html, menu

Ok so i got a menu like this

```
    <a id="page1" onclick="page1" href="">Home</a>
    <a id="page2" onclick="page2" href="">About us</a>
    <a id="page3" onclick="page3" href="">Services</a>
    <a id="page4" onclick="page4" href="">Partners</a>
    <a id="page5" onclick="page5" href="">Contact us</a>
```

And since I'm working with one html file, need the javascript to be if page1 onclick then show this section but don't show page2, page3, page4, page5.

Since I'm terrible at javascript the best i could come up with is;

```
<script>
var one = document.getElementById('page1');
if (page1 == page1){
    document.write("<html> psuedo html code goes here</html>");
}
</script>
```

Hope you guys can help.
Thank you anyway

Comment: you probably need to add urls to those links and then look into using ajax to load the content into your page, but as it stands you will need to put a bit more effort into this as the question is way too broad for this forum

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you right and this is what you want:

https://jsfiddle.net/0zv9d302/1/

```
$(document).on('click', '.navigation a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var section = $(this).attr("id");
  $(".content div").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("class") == section){
        $(this).show();
    } else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
  })
});
```

This is just a quick way how you could do it with jQuery.
I also want to show you a way to do this using Bootstrap Framework, just give me some more time for this.

---

**EDIT**

Here you go doing it with bootstrap:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">About us</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Services</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Partners</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>Home</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>About us</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Services</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Partners</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu4" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Contact us</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0zv9d302/2/

You don't even need extra Javascript/jQuery if you include the bootstrap library.

Comment: @TimMarshall No problem man. Please accept this answer as the solution and give it an "arrow up" if it helped you :) thanks